# Python pandas gives UnicodeDecodeError 'charmap' codec can't decode byte error when compression is set to gzip

Tags: python, pandas, gzip

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list_item_data)
df.to_csv("out.csv", sep="\t", index = False, encoding='utf8', compression='gzip')
```

Python pandas gives

> UnicodeDecodeError at /feeds/google/ 'charmap' codec can't decode
>   byte 0x83 in position 2161: character maps to  error when
>   compression is set to gzip.

Is there any other way to gzip this file, or solve this problem?

Comment: use `encoding='iso8859'`

Comment: Changing encoding just gives me UnicodeEncodeError at /feeds/google/
'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 26-27: ordinal not in range(256), even when compression isn't set.

Comment: When I update pandas to 0.23.4, it starts working.